# custom view multitouch crash

Tags: android, view

When I multitach my custom views I have a crash:

```
11-12 21:54:23.048: W/System.err(9625): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
11-12 21:54:23.048: W/System.err(9625):     at android.view.MotionEvent.getX(MotionEvent.java:972)
11-12 21:54:23.048: W/System.err(9625):     at android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompatEclair.getX(MotionEventCompatEclair.java:32)
11-12 21:54:23.048: W/System.err(9625):     at android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat$EclairMotionEventVersionImpl.getX(MotionEventCompat.java:91)
11-12 21:54:23.048: W/System.err(9625):     at android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat.getX(MotionEventCompat.java:219)
11-12 21:54:23.048: W/System.err(9625):     at com.ex.app.views.PulledItem.determineDrag(PulledItem.java:399)
11-12 21:54:23.048: W/System.err(9625):     at com.ex.app.views.PulledItem.onInterceptTouchEvent(PulledItem.java:290)
11-12 21:54:23.048: W/System.err(9625):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:960)
11-12 21:54:23.048: W/System.err(9625):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1015)
11-12 21:54:23.048: W/System.err(9625):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1015)
11-12 21:54:23.048: W/System.err(9625):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1015)
11-12 21:54:23.048: W/System.err(9625):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1015)
11-12 21:54:23.048: W/System.err(9625):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1015)
11-12 21:54:23.048: W/System.err(9625):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1015)
11-12 21:54:23.048: W/System.err(9625):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1015)
11-12 21:54:23.048: W/System.err(9625):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1015)
11-12 21:54:23.048: W/System.err(9625):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1015)
11-12 21:54:23.048: W/System.err(9625):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1015)
11-12 21:54:23.048: W/System.err(9625):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1015)
11-12 21:54:23.048: W/System.err(9625):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1015)
11-12 21:54:23.048: W/System.err(9625):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1820)
11-12 21:54:23.048: W/System.err(9625):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1176)
11-12 21:54:23.058: W/System.err(9625):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2198)
11-12 21:54:23.058: W/System.err(9625):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1795)
11-12 21:54:23.058: W/System.err(9625):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2336)
11-12 21:54:23.058: W/System.err(9625):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1976)
11-12 21:54:23.058: W/System.err(9625):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-12 21:54:23.058: W/System.err(9625):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
11-12 21:54:23.058: W/System.err(9625):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
11-12 21:54:23.058: W/System.err(9625):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 21:54:23.058: W/System.err(9625):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-12 21:54:23.058: W/System.err(9625):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-12 21:54:23.058: W/System.err(9625):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-12 21:54:23.058: W/System.err(9625):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It appears at `getX`

```
private void determineDrag(final MotionEvent event) {
        final int activePointerId = mActivePointerId;
        final int pointerIndex = getPointerIndex(event, activePointerId);
        if (activePointerId == -1)
            return;
        float x;
        float dx;
        float xDiff;
        float y;
        try {
            x = MotionEventCompat.getX(event, pointerIndex);
            dx = x - mInitMotionX;
            xDiff = Math.abs(dx);
            y = MotionEventCompat.getY(event, pointerIndex);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
```

Try-catch is solution but I want to know is this Android bug or something else?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an Android bug yes. It seems the support library may not be doing good (or any) bounds checking in some cases.

Basically you end up with random/seldom crashes in  `onTouchEvent()` or `onInterceptTouchEvent()` either with a  `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range` (bug report [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64553)) or a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` (bug report [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61518)) It seems to be manifested when people multitouch. It's hard to reproduce.

The workaround for this issue (and a similar ones) seems to be so subclass and override  `onTouchEvent()` and `onInterceptTouchEvent()` where you catch these exceptions and return `false`. See code example [here](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/issues/36#issuecomment-15455852).